# Rode NTG3 vs Sennheiser MKH 416

Tags: microphone, audio, recording

I am pretty torn between the Rode NTG3 and the Sennheiser MKH 416.
The Sennheiser MKH 416 is considered to be the industry standard and is considered by many as probably one of the best in the market. However, I also read a lot online from users who've had and used both and say they would surprisingly recommend the Rode NTG3. A lot of opinions online seem to say that the NTG is practically just as good as the MKH while being significantly cheaper (at almost half the price).
So my question is, is it worth it to get the MKH 416 and spend big dollars for the "industry standard" or to save some money and just go with the NTG3.
Opinions and preferences aside, objectively, what are the differences between the two mics such as the specs etc.

Comment: you should be looking at the NTG5

Answer (score -1):

Which one did you end up getting?  I ended up picking up the NTG3 and NTG5 because I couldn't afford the MKH 416.  What I realized is that unless you have the perfect recording environment and the ideal listening environment (high quality headphones, etc), it is hard to tell the difference even between the NTG2 ($269 shotgun mic) and the NTG3 ($699 shotgun mic).

Check out this video: